# InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException

Tags: powershell, asp.net-core-webapi

I am testing a Web Core API and I am getting a 500 Internal Server error.
My method on my controller is;

```
[Route("api/property")]
public class PropertyController : BaseSirController
{

    [HttpPost("{contractId}/saveproperty")]
    public IActionResult SaveProperty(int contractId, [FromBody] PropertyContractDto property)
    {
        if (property == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        if (contractId == 0)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok();
        //return CreatedAtRoute("GetPropertyInspectionsForContract", new {contractId = contractId}, properties);
    }
```

and in my POwershell command I enter:

```
Invoke-RestMethod http://localhost:17972/api/property/7/saveproperty -Method POST -Body (@{UPRN="1244"; StreetName="The Street"; AddressLine2="ALine2"; AddressLine3="ALine3"; AddressLine4="ALine4"; Postcode="N1 7PL"; Latitude="23"; Longitude="77"; BlockUPRN="B1244"; PropertyNo="23"; BlockName="Wenlock Court"; Comments="blah blah blah"; PropertyTypeId="1"; NumberOfBathrooms="1"; NumberOfBedrooms="2"; NumberOfKitchens="1"; PropertyContractId="23"; PropertyType="Maisonette"} | ConvertTo-Json) -ContentType "application/json"
```

The error message I am getting is;

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod http://localhost:17972/api/property/7/saveproperty -Method POS ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

I cannot work out how to fix this.

Comment: Given how simple the server code is I'm going to guess this is a parameter issue. Firstly I can't see where you're sending `contractId`, and secondly from some quick reading I'm not convinced the `PropertyContractDto` object is being passed correctly. This isn't exactly my area of expertise but that's where I'd be looking.

Comment: The contractId is 7 and it is coming through OK. The problem is the payload being sent after the [FromBody] attribute. I do not know why this is a problem.

Comment: Ahh I see now. Have you tested casting JSON to the PropertyContractDto class?

Comment: I am not clear on what you mean

Comment: You have a presumably custom type PropertyContractDto being accepted as a parameter, but what you're sending is essentially a string. You're then attempting to cast that string to to the PropertyContractDto object (similar to `[Int]"5"`), if it doesn't have the appropriate constructor to handle this it will fail. You are probably better off accepting the parameter as the type it is being passed in, then parse it to the desired type. If that fails you can throw an appropriate error. Eg, does `[FromBody] Object property` work?

Comment: Hello! Do you have this : <%@...validateRequest=false%> on the page that receives the request =) ?

Comment: I tried posting just a single string, but I go the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem was in my Startup.cs, ConfigureServices method. If I put in `services.AddMvcCore().AddJsonFormatters();` it works